# Gwt - Showing a pop up panel when user's touch more than one widget or link

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I am creating a panel showing many different kind of widgets such as button. The panel allows to zoom in and zoom out. It is required to show whole panel in the beginning. However, some users may touch more than one button when the panel is too small.

I want to handler the situation like chrome in Android. When the user touches more than one link, a pop up panel will be showing.
What library or APIs may I use?
Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to use touch event(touchStart, TouchEnd, TouchMove). My idea is that there is a count to record widget number. And when touch en, if more than one button is touched, showing a panel.      
public void onTouchStart(TouchStartEvent event) {
 count++;
}

public void onTouchEnd(TouchEndEvent event) {
 if (count == 1) {
  //Do Action
 } else {
  //Showing Popup Zoom in panel
 }
 count = 0;
}

Comment: However, the problem is that when only one touch point covering more than one button, the device will select one of the button not to trigger the logic

Answer (score 1):

You could place your Buttons in a FocusPanel implementing a ClickHandler to open your desired popup- thus when your user clicked between two buttons the click is registered and you can handle it.

Note, you will have to place a FlowPanel in that FocusPanel to place more than one button inside.

If you want to react on hover instead of on click, use HoverHandler instead.